# FME - Is it possible to add custom command line input arguments to a workspace?

Tags: fme-form, translation

I have a workspace whose command line call is like so:

```
fme.exe DwgImporter.fmw
          --SourceDataset_ACAD Z:\FME\Data\DWGs\*.dwg
          --DestDataset_MSSQL_ADO IHS_TPW
          --SourceDataset_GEODATABASE_SDE sde
```

Is it possible to somehow add my own custom input arguments that can then be read from within the workflow? Something like:

```
fme.exe DwgImporter.fmw
          --SourceDataset_ACAD Z:\FME\Data\DWGs\*.dwg
          --DestDataset_MSSQL_ADO IHS_TPW
          --SourceDataset_GEODATABASE_SDE sde
          --CustomArg1 arg1
          --CustomArg2 arg2
```

Or does anyone know of another way to pass in variables at runtime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ParameterFetcher**

http://www.fmepedia.com/index.php/ParameterFetcher#Command_Line_Example

Answer (score 5):

More generally, you need what is called a "published parameter" -- you don't have to use the ParameterFetcher to pull them out in a workflow either.  This FAQ http://fmepedia.safe.com/articles/FAQ/Can-I-pass-a-variable-to-FME-to-replace-a-fixed-value-within-a-workspace describes what I'm talking about very concisely, and if you grab section 4 of the online FME self study course at http://www.safe.com/support/onlinelearning/selfstudy.php, on page 4-24 and 4-25 these are explained more as well.

Hope this helps.

Dale